# ModuleNotFoundError when importing installed module in venv

Tags: python, import, visual-studio-code, python-venv, modulenotfounderror

I installed a library inside a virtual environment using `venv` in Visual Studio Code, then imported it into a Python file. However, when I run the file, I get a ModuleNotFoundError.

Attempted steps and checks:

- I do not have multiple versions of Python installed.
- I activated the venv before installing the module and before running the file.
- VS Code says that it is using the Python executable in \venv\scripts.
- The module is in fact in `venv\Lib\site-packages`.
- I am running the latest version of pip both within and without the venv.
- I restarted VS Code.

Oddities:

- Running the file from the built-in terminal works rather than raising an error.
- `which python` in Bash returns `/c/Users/Lyndon/Documents/VS Code/seatmap_parser/\Users\Lyndon\Documents\VS Code\seatmap_parser\venv/Scripts/python` when it should presumably return `C:\Users\Lyndon\Documents\VS Code\seatmap_parser\venv\Scripts\python`.
- Adding the setting `"python.pythonPath": "${workspaceRoot}/venv/Scripts/python"` to workspace `settings.json` raises this error: `The Python path in your debug configuration is invalid.`
- If I deactivate the venv, install the module globally, and reactivate the venv, the file now works, leading me to think that perhaps somehow the wrong Python executable is running anyway.

I stand ready to check for any missed details upon request. Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get OUTPUT just clicking `run` in a specified file, then you have to go user settings. Enter your python path in `"code-runner.executorMap`" dict after "python" key. If not specified just type `code-runner.executorMap` and it will generate that dict for you.

Comment: Oh. So the venv works only in the terminal?

Comment: Yeah, in case you have not specified path in Code-Runner Extension which executes and produces output in "OUTPUT"  block near Terminal.